# Moment of inerta of square frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

A rod of length $l$ and mass $m$ has $ml^2/12$ as moment of inertia about an axis through its center of mass.

[image: a]
<sub>(source: [draw.to](http://draw.to/static/d/3xaD9u.png?v=13168))</sub>

Say now we take four identical copies of the rod above and form a square frame, whose center of mass lies exactly at the geometric center of the square. How can we then use the moment of inertia of a single rod to calculate the moment of inertia of the entire square frame?

[image: a]
<sub>(source: [draw.to](http://draw.to/static/d/3foGwV.png?v=9bd85))</sub>

I recently began learning about moment of inertias so I am not really sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Here's a crude way: let λ be the linear mass density (λ = m/l). 
In the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6RkS.png), 
$$dI = r^2 dm = (x^2 + \frac {l^2}4)\ λ dx$$
$$I = λ \int ^{\frac l2}_0 (x^2 + \frac{l^2}4 )dx = \frac{ml^2}6$$ Moment of inertia of square will be 8 times of above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) to work out the moment of inertia of a rod of length $l$ with it's centre of mass displaced from the axis of rotation by $\frac{l}{2}$ then multiply this value by four to get the moment of inertia of the whole square.

The parallel axis theorem is:

\begin{equation}
I = I_{cm} + md^2
\end{equation}

Where $I$ is the moment of inertia when the object has been displaced, $I_{cm}$ is the moment of inertia of the object when the axis of rotation passes through the centre of mass and $d$ is the distance it is displaced.

For each rod in your square we have:

\begin{align}
I_{cm} &= \frac{1}{12} ml^2 \\
d &= \frac{l}{2}\\
I &=  ml^2 \left(\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{4} \right) = \frac{ml^2}{3}
\end{align}

So multiplying by four gives:

\begin{equation}
I_{square} = \frac{4ml^2}{3}
\end{equation}

Comment: or1426's answer is mostly correct but $m$ is the mass of one rod so the mass of the square is $M=4m$. So the correct equation should be $$I=\frac{ML^2}{3}$$